# Hyphens in serialized JSON OpenStruct

Tags: ruby

I have a JSON object such as:

```
"c": {
    "10-20": 9.0,
    "0-10": 8.5,
    "30-end": 5.085714285714286,
    "20-30": 10.3
}
```

When I convert that JSON to a serialized object using:

```
JSON.parse(response.body, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

It gives me:

```
<OpenStruct 10-20=0, 0-10=8.5, 30-end=5.085714285714286, 20-30=10.3>
```

Naturally that can't be accessed with c.10-20 as I don't believe hyphens are valid class variable names. So, how do you access these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets like you would with a hash:

```
obj["10-20"]
#=> 0
```

Of course, if most of the keys are not valid method names anyway, then you might as well just use a hash and not bother with an `OpenStruct`.

Related documentation: **[OpenStruct#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-5B-5D)**